# sqlite trigger on insert to check redundancy on table or update

Tags: sqlite, triggers, upsert, redundancy

I am working on trigger before or after inserting record to table to check if the name exist on table rather update the date. 
I know using Insert into on Conflict Do Something works in sqlite 3.24 and I am trying to use this to make a trigger but I have lack of understand in trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER redun_check BEFORE INSERT on address
BEGIN
INSERT INTO address (address_name, lat, lng, `date`) VALUES (new.address_name, 
new.lat, new.lng, new.`date`) on CONFLICT (address_name) do UPDATE SET `date` = 
excluded.date;
END
```

if the address name is existing update the date rather than insert
or is there any other way to reduce the redundant record and when insert rather do update on table.

```
CREATE TABLE "address" (
"address_id"    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
"address_name"  TEXT UNIQUE,
"lat"   BLOB NOT NULL,
"lng"   BLOB NOT NULL,
"date"  NUMERIC
)
```

this is my table. I really need help on this thanks

Comment: Um... why are you trying to use a trigger at all? Just an insert with the upsert ON CONFLICT is enough.

Comment: i am using my sqlite database along with android studio and what i want is when data is inserted i want my database to  automatically trigger to determine whether to insert or update @Shawn